# Is getrandmax() a fix number?

Tags: php, function, random, numbers

In getrandmax() i get a value max of 2147483647
It is the same on all the computer, or does it change and can be increased/decresed ?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php says _"Note: On some platforms (such as Windows), getrandmax() is only 32767. If you require a range larger than 32767, specifying min and max will allow you to create a range larger than this, or consider using mt_rand() instead."_. So that might help answer your query

Comment: Same page as @ADyson mentioned: _rand() is now an alias of mt_rand()_  And from the notes on [`mt_getrandmax()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-getrandmax.php): _The upper-bound of this value is platform-independent.  PHP implements the 32-bit version of the Mersenne Twister ("mt"), so the maximum possible value is 2**31 - 1 (2147483647)._

Comment: Let's get down to earth. The whole idea of using a function call, to get the max value, is precisely because it will not always be the same. I think you can assume it will be the same while a script executes, but other than that, don't make any assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getrandmax() will typically be tied to the system architecture. The highest unsigned number.

For example 2147483647 is 2^31-1.

Other systems may have 2^15-1 = 32767 (documented as on some Windows systems).

I’ve yet to see a 64 bit version. But it would be 2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807.